# Show that $\ln$ is bijective.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a map $\ln:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt~~(x>0)$. Show that $\ln$ is bijective.

I don't understant whether this probolem is correct. If I solve RHS of $\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$ then we get $\ln x=\ln x-\ln 1+c$(integral constant).
Which makes me ambigious.

Injectivity seems obvious to me:

$\ln x=\ln y\Leftrightarrow x=y$.

How to check surjectivity?

Comment: The map has an inverse

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Can we solve except this way?

Comment: Downvoter plase leave a comment.

Comment: A way to prove surjectivity is through the Intermediate Value Theorem noticing that the limit of $log(x)$ when $x \to 0+$ is $- \infty$ and when $x \to \infty$ is $+ \infty$. In order to prove this two statements you should first verify some properties of the $log$ function such as $log(xy)=log(x)+log(y)$ and $log(x^n)=n \cdot log(x)$.

Comment: @freakish As $t>0$, so $\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt>0. \ln$ is increasing thus $\ln$ is injevtive. Am i right?

Comment: When you integrate $\int_x^y f$, there is no integration constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition is $\ln x=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt~~(x>0)$. You cannot "solve it", its a definition. Maybe you should replace "$\ln$" with "$F$" to avoid confusion. Also your "injectivity proof" isn't a proof at all. You just stated what "injectivity" means and claimed that it is obvious. The real solution is to realize that $\ln x$ is increasing because $\frac{1}{t}$ is continuos and positive for $t>0$.

---

Indeed, assume that $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, everywhere positive function. It follows that $\int_x^y f(t)dt>0$ for any $1<x<y$. Therefore, given $1<x<y$ we have

$$\int_1^y f(t)dt=\int_1^x f(t)dt+\int_x^y f(t)dt>\int_1^x f(t)dt$$

Which shows that for $F(x)=\int_1^x f(t)dt$ we have $F(y)>F(x)$ whenever $y>x$. Thus $F$ is (strictly) increasing, in particular injective.

---

As for surjectivity we will have to look at our specific $F(x)=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$ case. First of all it is a general theorem that [an antiderivative is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290677/antiderivative-is-continuous), in particular it satisfies the intermediate value property. And so our $F$ is continuous. Now secondly

$$F(1/x)=\int_1^{1/x}\frac{1}{t}dt=-\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt=-F(x)$$

The equality in the middle is a careful [integraton by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ (I leave details as an exercise).

Now the second thing is that given a natural $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have

$$\int_1^n\frac{1}{t}dt \geq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}$$

In particular, since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i}$ series diverges to infinity, it follows that $F(x)\to\infty$ when $x\to\infty$ (due to the fact that $F$ is increasing). By our $F(1/x)=-F(x)$ rule we get that $F(x)\to-\infty$ when $x\to 0$.

All those facts together allow to apply the intermediate value property to conclude that every real in $\mathbb{R}$ is attainable by $F(x)$, i.e. it is surjective.

Comment: Beautiful answer but I am still struggling for surjectivity.

Comment: @user955446: If you need to do that from absolute scratch without knowing anything about logarithms, googling for proofs of "the harmonic series diverges" should give you the building blocks for showing that there's space for rectangles with arbitrarily high total area under the graph of $1/t$ either to the left or to the right of $1$ -- so your function must reach arbitrarily large positive or negative values.

Comment: @user955446, As mentioned in the comment, you may first show that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \ln x = +\infty \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{x\to0^+}\ln x = -\infty. $$ Together with the intermediate value theorem, you are now good to go.

Comment: I've updated the answer.